# Multiple async writes to the same file in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am writing modifications to a file based upon user input using `fs.writeFile(...)`. I recently encountered a bug where two write requests came in effectively causing the file to be truncated.

Each write operation must complete in the order it was received. However I don't want the user to have to wait for the write to complete before they can move on to their next task.

What is the canonical way or popular module to queue the async writes such that the user is not prevented from doing other work while the writes happen, and to guarantee collision does not occur.

Additionally I'd like reads to happen to the same file if possible.

My initial thoughts would be write a temp file and then copy, but that seems not as efficient.

Comment: Is this the multiple writes from only one process or from multiple processes?

Comment: Perhaps `fs.appendFile()` which just appends data to a file.

Comment: fs.appendFile won't work as I do sorted inserts. And it is a single process. Actually an express app where the file reading/writing is in its own module. The idea is that a user makes a modification which is written off to a separate file, then the user will approve the modifications at which point the modifications are inserted into the original file. The truncation happened when multiple approvals happened in close succession.

Comment: *"What is the canonical way or popular module to queue the async..."* use an [async queue](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async/#queue). :)

Comment: 2022 and the problem STILL EXISTS :) I'm so happy finally having found somebody that confirms my mistery-appended-files. In my case the Nuxt static site generator script sometimes writes different states into the same state.js file, causing appended broken state files that break the whole JS on page. Knowing the source of the issue I'm off to prepare some PR ... did you finally use the proposed async.queue approach?

Answer (score 5):

Use async.queue from the async module to create a task runner with a concurrency of 1 (only one operation can run at a time). When a new edit occurs add it to the queue. Your logic would be as follows:

1. Add task to queue.
2. When task runs read the existing file.
3. Perform your write logic.
4. Call the async queue callback so the next queued write can occur.